# create new worksheet after cell (in a range) change

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells A2 through A20
Would like to generate a new worksheet when cell values within that range change.

Additionally, the new worksheet generated would be renamed to the value of the changed cell.

I had this code working properly (for a single cell), until the range was requested by the user

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set KeyCells = Range("B5")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
For Each ws In Worksheets
With ActiveSheet
    If .Range("B5").Value <> "" Then .Name = .Range("B5").Value
End With
Cells(lastrow, "D").Value = Range("B5").Value
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below creates a new worksheet once a value inside `Range("A2:A20")` has changed, the new worksheet name equals the cell value.

The code also verifies that there is no exitsing sheet with that name (that will result with an error).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

' you are not doing anything currently with the last row
'lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' according to your post you are scanning Range A2:A20 (not B5)
Set KeyCells = Range("A2:A20")

If Not Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ' if sheet with that name already exists
        If ws.Name = Target.Value Then
            MsgBox "A Worksheet with Cell " & Target.Value & " already exists"
            Exit Sub
        End If                  
    Next ws

    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Name = Target.Value        
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: perfect. thanks. lastrow and A2:A20 were part of other requests. thanks for ignoring.